# ADL warning: ambiguous conversion with boost operators and SFINAE

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, operators

I'm trying to understand an ambiguous conversion warning during ADL for the following piece of code:

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>

class Scalar
    : private boost::multiplicative< Scalar, double > {
  public:
    explicit Scalar( double val ) : mVal( val ) {}
    Scalar &operator*=(double rhs) noexcept {
        mVal *= rhs;
        return (*this);
    }

    Scalar &operator/=(double rhs) noexcept {
        mVal /= rhs;
        return (*this);
    }
  private:
    double mVal;
};

using Coordinate = int;
using Polygon = boost::polygon::polygon_with_holes_data<Coordinate>;
using Point = boost::polygon::polygon_traits<Polygon>::point_type;

template <class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>>
Point operator*(const Point &a, T b) noexcept {
   return Point(a.x() * b, a.y() * b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Scalar a( 10 );
    int b = 10;
    Scalar a_times_b = a * b;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following warning for GCC 11.2:

```
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
<source>:33:28: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
   33 |     Scalar a_times_b = a * b;
      |                            ^
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_78_0/boost/operators.hpp:268:1: note: candidate 1: 'Scalar boost::operators_impl::operator*(const Scalar&, const double&)'
  268 | BOOST_BINARY_OPERATOR_COMMUTATIVE( multipliable, * )
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:26:7: note: candidate 2: 'Point operator*(const Point&, T) [with T = int; <template-parameter-1-2> = void; Point = boost::polygon::point_data<int>]'
   26 | Point operator*(const Point &a, T b) noexcept {
      |       ^~~~~~~~
<source>:33:12: warning: variable 'a_times_b' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   33 |     Scalar a_times_b = a * b;
      |
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/qzfvjr86c.  One way to fix this is to also inherit from `boost::multiplicative< Scalar, int >` and perhaps also define the operators *= and /= for `int` (which is technically unnecessary since we get implicit conversions from `int` to `double`).

My Confusion:

For the so called "first" there is a implicit built in `int->double` conversion.  For the so called "second" is the compiler talking about some conversion from the Scalar class to Point?  I'm not sure what this conversion chain looks like as I haven't defined any way for the Scalar class to be converted to a Point.  Is there something I'm missing with the enable if?  Is this some sort of bug in Boost or GCC?

Comment: "Is there something I'm missing with the enable if" - I suppose: it's too open and leads to "equally bad" overloads-matches-by-implicit-conversion

Comment: @sehe I'm not sure why it's "equally bad".  For example, If I get rid of the SFINAE and just define `operator*(const Point &a, int b)` I still get the ambiguous conversion warnings even though there is no way to convert a `Scalar` to a `Point`.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I *am* sure the compiler is going to great lengths to explain exactly that to you by writing an error novel about it. I'm not actually in the habit of reading those unless I **absolutely** have to. Instead I avoid overly open overloads and employ ADL/ADL barriers to be selective. This implies not having operators at global namespace and rarely `using` them inside a scope (unless I willingly take the risk that the code will break in the future when new overloads appear)

Comment: I get the same warning if I remove the inheritance and just define the operator as a friend function.  Guess it's the compilers fault...

Comment: It never is*. It's some assumptions about `Point` constructability: [no problem](https://godbolt.org/z/hY7afoe3d) vs [using Boost Polygon](https://godbolt.org/z/7nezo6cac)
(*some conditions apply). Again, your problem is that the global namespace overload is way too open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your free `operator*` in the global namespace is too open. It actively assumes that `Point` is not constructible from `Scalar`, quod non:

- [no problem](https://godbolt.org/z/hY7afoe3d)
- vs [using Boost Polygon's Point](https://godbolt.org/z/7nezo6cac)

You should restrict it more:

```
template <
    typename P, typename S,
    typename IsPoint = typename boost::polygon::is_point_concept<
        typename boost::polygon::geometry_concept<P>::type>::type,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<IsPoint::value and std::is_arithmetic_v<S>>>
auto operator*(P const& a, S const& b) noexcept {
    return boost::polygon::construct<Point>(a.x() * b, a.y() * b);
}
```

I also suggest you

- as shown, use the point traits to construct the point instead of assuming direct construction
- don't put operator templates in global namespace (not shown)
- use `boost::polygon::scale` that already exists and likely has more safeties and/or optimization (not shown)

### Live Demo

[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/P5dej4WPf)

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Scalar {
    explicit Scalar(double val) : mVal(val) {}

private:
    friend Scalar operator*(Scalar lhs, double rhs) noexcept {
        lhs.mVal *= rhs;
        return lhs;
    }

    double mVal;
};

#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
using Coordinate = int;
using Polygon    = boost::polygon::polygon_with_holes_data<Coordinate>;
using Point      = boost::polygon::polygon_traits<Polygon>::point_type;

template <
    typename P, typename S,
    typename IsPoint = typename boost::polygon::is_point_concept<
        typename boost::polygon::geometry_concept<P>::type>::type,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<IsPoint::value and std::is_arithmetic_v<S>>>
auto operator*(P const& a, S const& b) noexcept {
    return boost::polygon::construct<Point>(a.x() * b, a.y() * b);
}

static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<double>);
static_assert(not std::is_arithmetic_v<Scalar>);

int main()
{
    auto s = Scalar(10) * 10;
    auto p = Point(10, 20) * 42;
}
```